# When using a form that takes to the main website

Tags: javascript

I am doing a form window before you get in the main website so I tried to make it so that if you don't fill any of the spaces it will open a window alert asking to fill those spaces. Plus I'd like that you would only get to the main website if you fill all the spaces but yet the button on the form window always takes to the main website without requiring filling of the camps.
On the button I wrote this:

```html
<a href="index1.html">
<input type="button" value="Terminar" onclick = location.href='index1.html' >
</a>
```

and on the js window I wrote the window alert command to each one of the categories:

```js
if(frm.name.value=="" || frm.name.value==null || frm.name.length < 3) {
alert("Please write your first name ")
        
frm.name.focus();
    
return false;
```

Comment: When exactly is your JS snippet being executed, and where are you getting `frm` from? I can't see any code which connects the snippet to the input button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to validate the an input field based on a few criteria.

Your question is not clear. Is this what you are trying to do?

```js
function validateInput() {
  if (frm.value == "" || frm.value == null || frm.value.length < 3) {
    alert("Please write your first name ")
    frm.focus();
  } else
    location.href = 'index1.html'
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="frm" placeholder="Please write your first name" />
<input type="button" value="Terminar" onClick="validateInput()">
```

Comment: Yes I did some editing on there and it was working thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this. In your code the input is wrapped in an a tag. so it will always trigger the event. Adding a button the trigger the event will help.

```js
button = document.getElementById('enter');
input = document.getElementById('fill');

button.onclick = function() {
  if (input.value == null || input.value == "" || input.value == " ") {
    alert('Please write your first name');
  } else {
    window.location.href = 'index1.html';
  }

};
```

```html
<input id="fill">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
```